# Hatching a rectangle leads to solid line in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

I would like to indicate an inequality constraint using a hatched pattern. This is to be done in a `pgfplot`, that is itself part of a `beamer` frame.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} 
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\textwidth,
                minor tick num=1,
                axis y line=center,
                axis x line=middle,
                ]
                \addplot[smooth, cyan, mark=none, domain=-3:3, samples=40, thick] {x^2};
                \draw[red, thick] (axis cs:-2, 0) -- (axis cs:-2, 9);
                \draw[pattern=north west lines, thin, red] (axis cs:-2,0)
                rectangle (axis cs:-1.75, 9);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

The resulting output, however, is:
[image: A solid line, not a pattern]

As you can see, a solid line is drawn rather than a pattern. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unrelated to the use of `beamer`. To specify the colour for the pattern, you have to use `draw=red, pattern color=red` instead of just `red`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\textwidth,
                minor tick num=1,
                axis y line=center,
                axis x line=middle,
                ]
                \addplot[smooth, cyan, mark=none, domain=-3:3, samples=40, thick] {x^2};
                \draw[pattern=north west lines, draw=red, pattern color=red] (axis cs:-2,0)
                rectangle (axis cs:-1.75, 9);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PS: change the question title to something more fitting if you can think of anyhting.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pattern color=red` should do the trick

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} 
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\textwidth,
                minor tick num=1,
                axis y line=center,
                axis x line=middle,
                ]
                \addplot[smooth, cyan, mark=none, domain=-3:3, samples=40, thick] {x^2};
                \draw[red, thick] (axis cs:-2, 0) -- (axis cs:-2, 9);
                \draw[pattern=north west lines, thin, pattern color=red] (axis cs:-2,0)
                rectangle (axis cs:-1.75, 9);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution in PSTricks just for fun.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Test}
\psgraph(0,0)(-3,0)(3,9){5cm}{6cm}
    \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue]{-3}{3}{x^2}
    \psframe[dimen=m,fillstyle=vlines,hatchcolor=red](-2,0)(-1.5,9)
\endpsgraph
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]